# circular dependency, how to get rid

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-providers

I tried to reproduce the problem in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xecn6c), but I do not have the warning in the blitz..

Basically,

my-module.module.ts import a component, so depend on it

```
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';
```

the component, use a service

```
import { MyServiceService } from '../my-service.service';
```

the service has

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyModuleModule
})
```

so depend on the module

```
import { MyModuleModule } from './my-module.module';
```

it looks circular to me, but where in my app I have warning, I do not have in stackblitz.

Is this correct implementation?

A fix would be remove the

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyModuleModule
})
```

But does this make my service provided in every module? or none of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the service

```
providedIn: 'root'
```

A service needs to be provided somewhere or else the dependency injection doesn't know where to get an instance from. Getting rid of the providedIn: MyModuleModule will error when you add it to a constructor list of dependencies. providedIn: 'root' means it doesn't need to be added to any modules.

Comment: Oh ok, so providedIn: 'root' will not add the module anywhere unless I specify it as provider ?